# When dequeuing an item in a queue, do the remaining items move up?

Tags: c++, data-structures, queue

this is a question regarding writing your own data structure programs (which appears to be called implementation I think?). I am using C++ to write.

When I did a stack assignment, popping something off the stack simply changed the index of the top variable as it was more about where the user can access items vs actually physically removing the item (it's not accessible once the top variable is changed, so my professor said these things don't actually need to be deleted/removed). Once top is moved down, there's more room for items on top.

In a queue, my understanding is that one dequeues from the front (first in, first out). When this happens, would all the remaining items need to be moved up one index?

For example, if I have a queue of 3, 5, 7 and I dequeue one, would I simply have an int variable called "front" that I increment from 0 to 1 so that front is now at the index for number 5? My concern is that by doing this, the queue will no longer be able to hold the max number of items, so I would think that I would move everyone down one index so that there is still room to add things at the back.

Comment: This depends heavily on how you're implementing the queue. You could have a circular queue wrapping around an array (in which case, you just need to keep track of the indexes of front and back: http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/171/Syllabus/8-List/array-queue2.html) or you could have a heap for a priority queue, in which case things do need to move around on a pop. How are you implementing this?

Comment: There are queues that move all items up, there are linked list (to be avoided), there are std::deque, there are ring-buffers/queues and probably more.

Comment: Regarding a basic queue, it's unusual to care about indexing at all.  In my eyes, a pure interface to a queue should not allow indexing.  It sounds like you're implementing a queue with a fixed maximum capacity, in which case you might consider a ring buffer implementation.  It's generally not a good idea to shift all the items when pushing or popping.  The user of a queue never expects that.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR yes, I would say you should move the elements

---

Let's start from the beginning:

> When I did a stack assignment, [...] my professor said these things
> don't actually need to be deleted/removed

It's important (imho) to understand why the professor said this.

First you need to be aware that this strategy works only for element types that have a trivial destructor (e.g. basic data types like `int`). This is a restriction of your particular implementation of the stack. Another limitation of your stack is that is has a limiting max capacity. A proper queue structure like [`std::stack`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack) has none of these shortcomings. This is perfectly fine for your assignment because implementing a stack without those restrictions would involve dynamic memory allocations and/or advanced techniques like placement new (or use an underlying container that already does all of this like `std::deque`). But the point of the assignment is to teach you the concepts of stack. Learning one new thing can be difficult. Learning 3 new and unrelated complex things at the same time would be irresponsible. So that's why your professor said "these things don't actually need to be deleted/removed".

Now let's go to the queue structure. Regardless of your choice your queue still has the above two limitations: applicable only for types with trivial destructor and unable to deal with unlimited elements.

If you move the elements then your queue will have the limitation of a (relatively small) maximum capacity (just like the stack you implemented)

If you don't move the elements then your queue will be limited to a maximum number of `push` operations, regardless of the `pop` operations. Just like you identified. So when the maximum push operations have been reached you can't push into the queue anymore, even if you poped or pop elements out of it.

The latter one is obviously more limited then the former. But since you already are supposed to implement a queue with limited capabilities the question is if the more limited one and the most easy to implement is acceptable in your exercise or not. Only your professor can clarify this. He/she can say something along the lines: "I am only interested you learn the abstract concepts of the queue and such you can assume/imagine an infinite capacity; you just need to deal with the indices and the correctness of push/pop operations". Or he/she can except you move the elements since it might be something you are already supposed to know how to do. However I would recommend to implement the moves regardless because it is not that difficult and is an useful skill.

As noted in the comments there are other ways of implementing a queue, like a circular queue.